# Once callable function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, time, timer

I am developing a quiz component in Javascript and I have a startTimer() function in it which starts a countdown based on the value passed to it. 
The function is called when the page loads and the quiz starts.

I don't what users to call the function again and alter the quiz time.

Is it possible to detect that the function is called a second time???

Comment: Yes, but users could change that too.

Comment: it needs to be programmed server-side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any user can just disable JavaScript in their browser.

I would suggest that you record the time between the page being served and the answers coming back on the server and use that as the definitive source for how long they took.  Perhaps allow a little buffer to compensate for network latency and page rendering time.

The JavaScript timer can be a nice UI feature to help the user know how much time they have left, but **never trust a user interface, for a smart user will write his own UI** (or in this case, configure the UI to not use JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent people from changing any aspect of the quiz, you will have to implement the restrictions on the server.

It will be very hard, if not impossible, to prevent meddling with the quiz data on the client side.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks everyone, I found this on net:

```
function createChance(){  
    var chanceLeft = true;  
    return function(){  
        if(chanceLeft){  
            console.log("This was the only chance you had.");  
             chanceLeft = false;  
        }  
        else{  
            console.log('Sorry: you already used your chance');  
        }  
    };  
}  

var chance = createChance();  
chance();  
 // This was the only chance you had.  
chance(); 
// Sorry: you already used your chance
```

any hacks for this????

Comment: This is using the same idea I had in my answer (using closures to close over chanceLeft). users can just do:
chance = function(){
 console.log("This was the only chance you had.");  
}

and override your chance function completely, since they have access to your code they'll know how to do so